# convert utf8 to ISO8859-1 using iconv command

Tags: unix, encoding, converters

I want to convert some utf8 files (text files) to ISO-8859-1 files. I use this command line :

```
iconv -c -f UTF-8 -t ISO8859-1 input_file > output_file
```

The file created (output_file) is indeed in the new encoding, even accentuated letters are good.

Just one character is not : the apostrophe... not the one corresponding to the one displayed on key 4 but one like the one you can do in a word file.

```
’
```

The problem is that it is converted to a SUB character, like something you would see if you open a word file in notepad++.

```
 (I copy the SUB here seen in notepad++ and it displays like that, obviously invisible when I submit this page)
```

In notepad++, there is a menu option to convert files from an encoding to another. There is no problem with any character. Is there something equivalent in Unix that can do the job?

Thank you

Comment: The character `’` does not exist in ISO-8859-1… it's somewhat unclear what the "correct" or expected result is.

Comment: Ok. I understand the causes of the problem.. is there a way to do like Notepadd ++ does ? it converts to ANSI with no problem. I tried to convert to ANSI too but the converter does not understand

Comment: Well, you could replace the `’` with something else before converting with `iconv`, like: `echo Frank’s ’ | sed "s/’/'/g"|iconv -f utf8 -t iso8859-1` would output `Frank's '`

Comment: I am not a unix professional. How would I do that using input_file and output_file like in the example

Comment: `sed "s/’/'/g" input_file | iconv [your params here] > output_file`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you could replace the `’` with something else (`'` below) before converting with `iconv`, like:

```
echo Frank’s ’ | sed "s/’/'/g" | iconv -f utf8 -t iso8859-1
Frank's '
```

To convert a file like that:

```
sed "s/’/'/g" input_file | iconv [your params here] > output_file
```

Comment: for some reason, the sed command does not replace the strange character

Comment: Is your shell's locale utf8 (type command `locale`, my output is `- - LC_ALL=en_US.utf8`)? What is your environment anyway?

Comment: LC_ALL is null or empty